# List Player Record Types, First Score, and Last Score

Tags: join, plpgsql

I have a `record_types` and a `record` table:

```
CREATE TABLE record_types(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  record_type VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO record_types(record_type) VALUES ('dribble');
INSERT INTO record_types(record_type) VALUES ('shooting');
INSERT INTO record_types(record_type) VALUES ('assist');

CREATE TABLE record(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  player_id BIGINT,
  record_type VARCHAR(50),
  score INT
);

INSERT INTO record(player_id,record_type,score) VALUES(603,'shooting',15);
INSERT INTO record(player_id,record_type,score) VALUES(603,'shooting',5);
INSERT INTO record(player_id,record_type,score) VALUES(604,'dribble',15);
INSERT INTO record(player_id,record_type,score) VALUES(604,'dribble',10);
INSERT INTO record(player_id,record_type,score) VALUES(604,'assist',15);
INSERT INTO record(player_id,record_type,score) VALUES(612,'shooting',20);
INSERT INTO record(player_id,record_type,score) VALUES(612,'shooting',5);
INSERT INTO record(player_id,record_type,score) VALUES(612,'dribble',10);
INSERT INTO record(player_id,record_type,score) VALUES(612,'assist',15);
```

What is the query for displaying this output:

```
|==========|============|==============|===============|
|player_id |record_type | first_score  | last_score    |
|==========|============|==============|===============|
|603       |dribble     | 0            | 0             |
|603       |shooting    | 15           | 5             |
|603       |assist      | 0            | 0             |
|604       |shooting    | 0            | 0             |
|604       |dribble     | 10           | 10            |
|604       |assist      | 15           | 15            |
|612       |shooting    | 5            | 5             |
|612       |dribble     | 10           | 10            |
|612       |assist      | 15           | 15            |
|==========|============|==============|===============|
```

This is what I got so far using DB-Fiddle
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7imvE5FVVHX8hpUkQGFgC/1

```
SELECT
  first_scores.player_id,
  first_scores.record_type,
  first_score,
  last_scores.record_type,
  last_score
FROM
(
  SELECT
    record.player_id,
    record.record_type,
    record.id,
    score AS first_score
  FROM record
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      player_id,
      MIN(record.id) AS min_record_id
    FROM record
    GROUP BY player_id
    ORDER BY player_id  
  ) AS min_scores
  ON min_record_id = record.id
  AND record.player_id = min_scores.player_id
) AS first_scores
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    record.player_id,
    record.record_type,
    record.id,
    score AS last_score
  FROM record
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      player_id,
      MAX(record.id) AS max_record_id
    FROM record
    GROUP BY player_id
    ORDER BY player_id  
  ) AS max_scores
  ON max_record_id = record.id
  AND record.player_id = max_scores.player_id   
) AS last_scores ON first_scores.player_id = last_scores.player_id
```